# ASP.NET ConfigurationErrorsException when serving images via UNC on IIS6

Tags: asp.net, iis-6, samba, unc, smb

I have a virtual directory in my web app which connects to a Samba share via UNC. I can browse the files via Windows Explorer without issue, but my web app throws a yellow screen with the following message:

> Description: An error occurred during
>   the processing of a configuration file
>   required to service this request.
>   Please review the specific error
>   details below and modify your
>   configuration file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: An error
>   occurred loading a configuration file:
>   Could not find file
>   '\cluster\cms\qa-images\120400\web.config'.

What makes no sense to me is why it's looking for a `web.config` in that location. I know it's not an authentication issue because the virtual directory can serve images from its root (i.e. `\\cluster\cms\qa-images\test.jpg` serves as `http://myserver/upload/test.jpg` just fine).

Ideas?

Comment: What have you tried so far to resolve this? Reboots? Checked permissions? Checked event logs? etc